# Disable dropbox Apps files.metadata.read permission

Tags: dropbox-api

For some security reason I hope to enable files.metadata.write and disable files.metadata.read in dropbox app permission setting but failed.

Is any that I can disable files.metadata.read permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox API scope "files.metadata.write" depends on "files.metadata.read", so it's not possible to enable "files.metadata.write" without also enabling "files.metadata.read".